# How do apps like Facebook handle MKMapView's in cells without stuttering

Tags: objective-c, facebook, uitableview, mkmapview

In my UITableView, whenever a cell with a MKMapView loads, the scrolling stutters pretty bad. I was wondering how Facebook accomplishes this without stuttering.

Comment: Are you sure map on facebook is actually MKMapView control? I think they are just snapshot(picture) and it display map view if you click on it in another view. and I don't think facebook uses UITableView either.

Comment: It shows the apple legal button in the bottom left. And if they are just snapshotting it, how do the do that off screen?